# javascript Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking

Hi I am working on simple js call between my websites,but I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: error .

Here is my code :

```
 <script>

$.getScript( "http://myts1.com/rotator.js?1418419096" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
new PFRotator({'width': '300', 'height': '250', 'vertical': '12, '}, 'PF300x250', '395953', '', '', 'Yes');
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "body" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});

</script>

ERROR : 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myts1.com/GETBANNERS.php?width=300&height=250&width=300&height=250&vertical=12%2C%20&mode=banner&mobile=false. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about the server that you want to make call.If it accepts cross origin requests this error wouldn't appear.You should check out the server configuration if it is belong to you.

Comment: Yes it belongs to me , can you please tell me how to make sure if it is ..

Comment: which language or framework did you used to create server side app?

Comment: it's in php , do I have to modify .htaccess ?

Comment: if it is an express application you can use express cors middleware check out here : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @AwaisArshad you can use php built in headers method to allow cross origin requests.Check that out

Answer (score 0):

Before making the request, set the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

You can also install a chrome extension that will do the job for you.

[This one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) has worked for me in the past.